# Getting Wix HTML element into iFrame variable

Tags: javascript, html, velo

I have a wix webpage with an HTML element on the page. I need to get the text of that element into my iFrame that contains javascript. I'd like to store that text of the html element as a variable in my iFrame javascript.

When I try the code below, my iFrame variable prints as 'undefined' in the web console.

```
<script>
var myElement = document.getElementById("#text15").text;
console.log(myElement);
</script>
```

Comment: I've also tried .innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript function [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) receives as parameter the string of the id value it should search in the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). So, you are searching for this:

```html
<div id="#text15"></div>
```

To find this element in the DOM:

```html
<div id="text15"></div>
```

You could either do:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("text15").innerText;
```

Or if you like using the hash symbol when referencing elements from the DOM, you can also try:

```
var myElement = document.querySelector("#text15").innerText;
```

Both work the same way. And also, use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) which references as the content inside the tag. The `text` property of the DOM element returned by JavaScript does not exist.

> **Note:** You should not reference your DOM elements right in a `<script>` tag. Since most likely the elements won't be ready by the time you call them.

Try:

```html
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var myElement = document.getElementById("#text15").innerText;
    console.log(myElement);
}
</script>
```

Look at an example of both ways:

```js
var text1=document.querySelector("#myElement").innerText;
console.log(text1);

var text2=document.getElementById("myElement").innerText;
console.log(text2);
```

```html
<div id="myElement">Hello!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#inPut').click(function() {
   var myElement = 
    $('#text15').val();

    console.log(myElement);
    
  });
 
});  
</script>


</head>
<body>
 
  
<br>
   <input type='text' id='text15'>
    
     <button id='inPut'>Write to console</button>

<br>
 </div>

   </body>
</html>
```